# replace char between pattern with c# and regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to improve a code using RegEx. Basically I have some patterns and I need to replace with the same pattern but using uppercase.

For example:

".a."

to

".A."

another pattern

"'a"

to

"'A"

I know a little bit about regex, but I don't know to replace to the same content but on uppercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Cyral said:

```
var str = "hello.a.world";
str = Regex.Replace(str, @'\.[a-z]\.', x => x.Value.ToUpper());
//str == "hello.A.world"
```

[This tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html) is a great reference for .NET's regular expression engine and regular expressions in general.

[Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) is a fantastic tool that I use frequently when I work with regular expressions.  It will spell out what the regular expression does, and allows you to test it out on sample text.  It also uses the same regex engine as .NET, so if your expression works in Expresso, it will work in C#.

Edit: Just to be clear, Cyral's answer is correct, I just wanted to be sure to add these links on to the page, as they are very helpful.

Comment: Wow I didn't see the lambda on his answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regex, you can just use [`String.ToUpper`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupper%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string str = ".a.";
str = str.ToUpper();
```

**EDIT:** To replace only from a pattern, run a function on the match: (Where `[a-z]` is your own regex)

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"[a-z]", s => s.Value.ToUpper());
```

Comment: I can't, I need to replace only when match the pattern, the rest should keep lowercase.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I have added another idea

Comment: I won't work. It's a kind of abreviation. I should keep lower case the full string. Only transform to uppercase when match those patterns. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Create a Regex for that and plug it into my code and it will work.